# What are the possible limits of the iteration $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{x_n+3}$, $x_0=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{x+3}$ for $x\ge -3$.
Consider the iteration $$x_{n+1}=f(x_n),x_0=0;n\ge 0$$ 
The possible limits of the iteration are

1. -1
2. 3
3. 0
4. $\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3+\cdots}}}$

I think only option 4. is correct as it the only one satisfying $x^2-x-3=0$

Comment: Yes, I agree. A limit $L$ of this sequence would be a *fixed point* of $f$, that is it would satisfy the equation $$f(L)=L \iff L=\sqrt{L+3} \iff L^2-L-3=0$$ which gives $L\approx 2.3$ (the negative root was rejected obviously). So, this must be the 4th option, the others do not match (however I did not evaluate the expression in the 4th option, I only excluded the rest).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right, but you should be looking at the equation $x=\sqrt{x+3}$.

The equation $x=\sqrt{x+3}$ has only one solution, and it happens to be in $(-3,+\infty)$.

The equation $x^2-x-3=0$ has two solutions, both of which are in $(-3,+\infty)$.

The options given make the distinction above irrelevant but it might not be so in other questions.

Answer (score 2):

You are right: The prospective limit would have to be a solution of
$$x^2=x+3,\quad x>0\ .\tag{1}$$
There is exactly one solution of $(1)$, namely
$$\xi:={1\over2}(1+\sqrt{13})\doteq2.3\ .$$
But the above argument does not prove that we actually have convergence. (For an example consider the sequence defined by $x_0:=2$, $x_{n+1}:=x_n^2$ $(n\geq0)$. Here $\xi=1$, but the sequence actually diverges.)  For a proof  that in the example of the question one indeed has  $\lim_{\to\infty}x_n=\xi$ put 
$$y_n:=\xi-x_n\quad(n\geq0)\ ,$$
with $y_0=\xi$. Then
$$y_{n+1}=\xi-x_{n+1}=\xi-\sqrt{x_n+3}=\xi-\sqrt{\xi^2-y_n}={y_n\over \xi+\sqrt{\xi^2-y_n}}\qquad(n\geq0)\ .$$
It is easy to see that $0<y_n\leq\xi<\xi^2$ implies
$$0<y_{n+1}<{y_n\over\xi}\leq1<\xi\ ,$$
so that we obtain $0<y_n\leq \xi^{1-n}$ $(n\geq0)$. This proves $\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n=0$ and hence our conjecture that $\lim_{\to\infty}x_n=\xi$.

The obtained limit differs from all options given. Note that option 4. is just a folklore rewriting of the problem and cannot be considered as its solution.

Comment: How to deny that $\lim x_n=\sqrt{3+\lim x_n}$ ?

Comment: @Ataulfo *If* $\lim x_n$ exists, then that equation holds, and then the limit can be solved for accordingly.  But how do you know it exists in the first place without investigating convergence?

Answer (score 1):

IMO, the answer $4$ is rather poor, as it is just a rewriting of the recurrence relation and doesn't tell you much more.

A much better one would be the positive root of the characteristic equation,

$$x=\frac{\sqrt{13}+1}2.$$